# Object issues C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop

I have no errors and it builds and runs but it doesn't show the vehicle type. All help appreciated. Im trying to store the string "car" in my object but its not working.

`string vType[] = {"Car","Van","Lorry","Motorbike","Tanker"};`

and i tried to use:

```
 Vehicle one;
one.setVehicleType(vType[0]);
cout << "Vehicle Type:" << one.getVehicleType() << endl;
```

Vehicle.ccp

```
#include "Vehicle.h"
Vehicle::Vehicle() {
vehicleMake = ' ';
}

Vehicle::Vehicle(string type){  
    vehicleVehicleType = type;

}

Vehicle::~Vehicle(){

}





//getMethods


string Vehicle::getFuelType()const{
    return vehicleFuelType;
}

string Vehicle::getVehicleType()const{
    return vehicleVehicleType;
}




//setMethods

void Vehicle::setMake(string make){
    vehicleMake = make;
}


void Vehicle::setVehicleType(string type){
    vehicleFuelType = type;
}
```

Vehicle.h

```
    class Vehicle{

    public:     
    //Default Constructor
        Vehicle();

    //Overload constructor
        Vehicle(char, string, string, string, string, int, int, int, int);

    //Destructor
        ~Vehicle();

    //Accessor Functions
        //get methods
        string vehicleType() const;

    void setVehicleType(string);
        //setFuelType - for Vehicle

    protected:  
        string vehicleVehicleType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're setting the wrong field here in the setter function:

```
void Vehicle::setVehicleType(string type){
    vehicleFuelType = type;
}
```

should be

```
void Vehicle::setVehicleType(string type){
    vehicleVehicleType = type;
}
```

And, as you have the appropriate constructor, this is a better way to create your object:

```
Vehicle one(vType[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're setting the wrong member here:

```
void Vehicle::setVehicleType(string type){
    vehicleFuelType = type;
}
```

You probably meant

```
void Vehicle::setVehicleType(string type){
    vehicleVehicleType = type;
}
```